# ASP.NET(VB) Can not find Global Application Class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0

My Visual Studio version is 2010 professional SP1.

.NET Framework version is 4

I have used `File/New/Web Site/ASP.NET Web Site`  (language is vb).

In `default.aspx`, I want to use `WebSite/Add New Item/Global Application class`  to create another .aspx page, but I can't find Global Application class

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your website for a Global.asax file.

You can only have one per website and Visual Studio will remove Global Application class if a Global.asax file already exists.